# Using collapsible panels within react-virtualized List

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-virtualized

I've managed to render a `react-virtulized List` to which I passed an array of `react-bootstrap Panels`. I've measured each of my rows, and via children callback, each time one of the child panels are clicked, an attribute in the parent state is updated. Said attribute is used inside the `react-virtualized List` `rowHeight()` function top check whether that panel is currently expanded. Then, using a `ref` to my `List`, i call the `recomputeRowHeights(index)` and `forceUpdateGrid()` methods on said`ref`.

The thing is, while the List component correctly updates both the height and position of my rows, the animation isn't smooth. I mean, the bootstrap expand animation works fine, but the change in height of the expanded row happens instantly after the click event, and then the animation starts, feeling somewhat chopy.

Is there any workaround for this, or is this an upcoming/planned/in the works feature for `react-virtualized`?

Comment: Hey Ramiro! Unfortunately, I have not spent much time working with or optimizing for resize animations within react-virtualized. It doesn't surprise me to hear that the resize/reposition is a bit choppy in the case you mention. If you could share your implementation with me as a Plnkr (or similar) I would be happy to take a look and make any suggestions though.

Comment: @brianvaughn Thanks a lot Brian!!
Here is the better i could do [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/SSzHqu8Ta18Oef80Eyzd?p=preview). Im sorry in advanced for the disaster you'are going to be seeing xD It's quite possible i missed something when i downsized it from the original project, though i hope not.
Once again, thanks for making the time for this!

Comment: No problem. Here's a quick-and-dirty example of one way you may add animation: https://plnkr.co/edit/VanCAQmSkUejp3hbJUyJ?p=preview. Not meant to be bug free, just an illustration. :D

Comment: wow! thanks for taking the time to pull that off, it definitely gives me some ideas.

Comment: Maybe you could add that as an answer so i can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I have not spent much time working with or optimizing for resize animations within react-virtualized. It doesn't surprise me to hear that the resize/reposition is a bit choppy in the case you mention.

Here's a quick-and-dirty example of one way you may add animation: plnkr.co/edit/VanCAQmSkUejp3hbJUyJ?p=preview. Not meant to be bug free, just an illustration. :D